# Views to display recent content with user pictures

Tags: views, users

I want to create a view displaying the recent content posted by users along with their respective pictures. I am able to Create the view displaying recent content but how to display the respective user picture who created the content along side the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a relation ship of the type content:author and use that relationship to add the user profile image.

Hope that helps.

EDIT : A description as per the comment

1) From RELATIONSHIPS(This would be in the advanced section on the right side) click on add. it will bring up a list of fields that you can add.

2) Add the Content: Author relation ship.

3) Now When you try to add the a field additional fields would be displayed related to the user you can select  User: Picture. The relationship author should be select.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply...can u tell me how do i use the relationship content:authot to add the user profile image